# Yesod Persona authentication problems when using Dockerized MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, docker, yesod, persona

We are developing an application using Yesod and MongoDB and we are having users authenticate using Mozilla Persona. However we have a development database that we use across development machines and also on our staging machine. Anytime development or testing data is added or removed from staging we synchronize it with the development machines using Docker. Here is the problem: even though our databases are exactly the same (thanks to Docker) we are encountering a situation in which we are able to log into the application on staging but not on the development machines. Basically Yesod refuses to log the application. Any ideas as to why is this happening? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your say "Yesod refuses to log the application". What does Yesold do/need in order to log the application ? Access to an account, a Tcpip/Ip port listening ? What does `docker logs xxx` show ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order to get help with this question, you need to provide more details on your configuration and what you've tried so far in order to troubleshoot the problem. For example, have you looked at your Yesod/MongoDB logs? Have you compared the databases to confirm they are actually the same (at least as far as required collections/data for Yesod)? If your configuration works on staging but not on development, perhaps there is a hard-coded value referring to the staging environment. There must be a more specific error than "refuses to log in".